# Conditional formatting error in Encoding(v) in R

Tags: r, conditional-formatting

I'm having an error when apply conditional formatting. I want to color red or highlight red the values in the last column that are higher than the column before. It's not a fixed column since I add a new column each time I run the code.

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)


file <- read_excel("path", col_names = TRUE)
posStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = rgb(1,0,0))
conditionalFormatting(file, cols = file[,ncol(file)], rows = 2:85, file[,ncol(file)]>file[,ncol(file) -1], 
                      style =  posStyle)
```

When i'm running it I get this error:
Error in Encoding(v) : a character vector argument expected

| Activity | Count | State | Count 2 | Count 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | Pending | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| xx | Pending | 2 | 3 | 2 |

I want for example the number 2 on count 3 to be red since is less than number 3 on count 2.

WHat does it means in this case?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please share a dput() of your data so we can see how the data is stored (see examples in the link I provided). Explicitly list any non-base R packages you are using. It’s not clear where these functions are coming from.

Comment: Putting wrong values for openxlsx options through `options()` gave me such a cryptic error message